# How to add authentication to ELSA dashboard?

Tags: elsa-workflows

Can anyone guide me on how can we add authentication to Elsa's dashboard? Right now, anonymous users can see the workflows and create. I want to restrict this behavior to specific users?

Answer (score 1):

The specifics probably depend on your .net version, but I believe what you want to do is set a fallback policy so that pages/controllers without [Authorize] attribute still require authentication.

Grabbed from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But in the case of Elsa, I don't have any code/controllers at my side, I'm just using the NuGet package. I don't want to go this route.

Comment: I don’t believe Elsa has any authentication framework of its own, it just plugs into the host’s authentication.